# File Issue "A server Error Occurr" when try to upload the file

Tags: craft3, files, filesystem

[image]When I try to upload the file OR go to the Asset section - I have Server Error Occurr error. In console I see the error that is somehow related with ?p=admin-lime/actions/element-indexes/get-elements and it returns 500

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the folder where your assets are being saved to does not have write permission. So check if that changes things.